# BarsCode Int25 into image in php

Tags: php, barcode

Hello I have to create a function which generates a barCode INT25 in php. Any ideas how to do it. The function should generate the image and give back the url where to find it.

Thank you very much

Comment: There is so much material on that. Some research wouldn't hurt and you would have a faster answer.

Comment: I tried several methods, including jQuery's barCode but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples, and libraries/classes, that can assist in this. Most of these, when you create the image, you save it instead of discarding. Then you can also post the url, or save it in a database for later use. Some examples are as follows:

- http://bmpradeep.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/generating-barcode-using-php/
- http://www.barcodephp.com/en/manual/i25
- http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-php-class-203.html
- http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/barcode-generator/barcode-generator/class/i25.barcode.php

Save file using php

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php